# Breakpoints inside CUDA kernel __global__ not hitting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

Using visual studios 2010. Win 7. Nsight 2.1

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

// incrementArray.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void incrementArrayOnHost(float *a, int N)
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i < N; i++) a[i] = a[i]+1.f;
}
__global__ void incrementArrayOnDevice(float *a, int N)
{
  int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  int j = idx;
  int i = 2;

  i = i+j; //->breakpoint here

  if (idx<N) a[idx] = a[idx]+1.f; //->breakpoint here
}
int main(void)
{
  float *a_h, *b_h;           // pointers to host memory
  float *a_d;                 // pointer to device memory
  int i, N = 10;
  size_t size = N*sizeof(float);
  // allocate arrays on host
  a_h = (float *)malloc(size);
  b_h = (float *)malloc(size);
  // allocate array on device 
  cudaMalloc((void **) &a_d, size);
  // initialization of host data
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) a_h[i] = (float)i;
  // copy data from host to device
  cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // do calculation on host
  incrementArrayOnHost(a_h, N);
  // do calculation on device:
  // Part 1 of 2. Compute execution configuration
  int blockSize = 4;
  int nBlocks = N/blockSize + (N%blockSize == 0?0:1);
  // Part 2 of 2. Call incrementArrayOnDevice kernel 
  incrementArrayOnDevice <<< nBlocks, blockSize >>> (a_d, N);
  // Retrieve result from device and store in b_h
  cudaMemcpy(b_h, a_d, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // check results
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) assert(a_h[i] == b_h[i]);
  // cleanup
  free(a_h); free(b_h); cudaFree(a_d);

  return 0;
}
```

I've tried inserting breakpoints as listed above inside my **global** void incrementArrayOnDevice(float *a, int N) but they're not hitting.

When I run debug (f5) in visual studios, I tried to step into incrementArrayOnDevice <<< nBlocks, blockSize >>> (a_d, N); but they would skip the entire kernel code section.

tried to add a watch on the variables i and j but there was an error "CXX0017: Error: symbol "i" not found."

Is this issue normal? Can someone please try on their pc and let me know if they can hit the breakpoints? If you can, what possible problem could mine be? Please help! :(

Comment: The code you are trying to set break points on doesn't exist in the compiler output. The CUDA compiler is very aggressive at removing "dead" code which doesn't have any result on memory writes in the kernel. If you make `a[idx]` depend on `i`, it should be retained by the compiler and you should be able to inspect it during debugging.

Comment: Are you doing local or remote debugging? I think _F5_ start a local debugging by default in Visual Studio, while Nsight -> Start CUDA Debugging will do it in the target you configured in the Launch Options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nsight debugging is different from VS debugging . You need to use Nsight debugging to hit the kernel breakpoints. However, for this you need 2 GPU cards. Do you have 2 cards in the first place? Please check

Comment: Nope, i'm running on a laptop's GPU. Geforce gt 520m. So is there no other way to debug the kernel if programming is done on a laptop? Thank you for your response. :)

Comment: @f0rfun: You can connect to an external computer with a GPU card for debugging. I know this is possible but have never done it before. SHould i modify my answer to include this or will you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug on a single GPU but on the following conditions:

1. You have to be using 5.0 toolkit
2. You have to be programming on a GPU that suports 303.xx NForceWare  or higher